# How to change the colour of carrier and clock in iOS and Android with IONIC?

Tags: ionic-framework

Looking for options to change the colour of the carrier and clock in iOS and Android. Please see attached image. I am using IONIC6 & Angular.

[image]

Comment: StatusBar.setBackgroundColor({
          color: "#1c6272"
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [@capacitor/status-bar](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/status-bar) plugin to change the color of the text or the bg.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this plugin, but it does not seem to be working on iOS.

Comment: It's working on our end. make sure you're placing it in the right method. Should be on app init.

Answer (score 0):

OK currently [@capacitor/status-bar](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/status-bar) does not support the **setBackgroundColor** method in iOS. So
to make it working we need to do some work around

I m using Capacitor 5 with ionic 7

go to your **XCODE**

you can override the function **setBackgroundColor** inside the CapacitorStatusBar Plugin in the path below

**Project Navigator > Pods > Development Pods > CapacitorStatusBar > StatusBarPlugin.swift**

```
@objc func setBackgroundColor(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
    let options = call.options

    if let color = options?["color"] as? String {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first {
                let statusBarView = UIView(frame: window.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame ?? CGRect.zero)
                if let uiColor = UIColor(hexString: color) {
                    statusBarView.backgroundColor = uiColor
                    window.addSubview(statusBarView)
                    if uiColor.isLight {
                        self.bridge?.statusBarStyle = .darkContent
                     } else {
                        self.bridge?.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    call.resolve([:])
}
```

also we need to add extension to support the UIColor

```
extension UIColor {
convenience init?(hexString: String) {
    
    var hexSanitized = hexString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    hexSanitized = hexSanitized.replacingOccurrences(of: "#", with: "")
    print("Failed to scan hex value.",hexSanitized)
    var rgb: UInt64 = 0

    guard Scanner(string: hexSanitized).scanHexInt64(&rgb) else { return nil }

    self.init(red: CGFloat((rgb & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
              green: CGFloat((rgb & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
              blue: CGFloat(rgb & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
              alpha: 1.0)
      }
  var isLight: Bool {
      var white: CGFloat = 0
      getWhite(&white, alpha: nil)
      return white > 0.7
  }
```

}

with the above code we can set the background color of status bar without any hassle. if you notice that here we have below code segment inside the extension

```
  var isLight: Bool {
    var white: CGFloat = 0
    getWhite(&white, alpha: nil)
    return white > 0.7
  }
```

what it does is, determining the current value of string which is passed through setBackgroundColor function is light or dark, by detecting that, we set the colors of texts | icons (Battery etc..) also in the status bar. you can see that code segment inside the **setBackgroundColor** method

```
 if uiColor.isLight {
    self.bridge?.statusBarStyle = .darkContent
 } else {
    self.bridge?.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
 }
```

finally your **StatusBarPlugin.swift** will look like below

```
import Foundation
import Capacitor

/**
 * StatusBar plugin. Requires "View controller-based status bar appearance" to
 * be "YES" in Info.plist
 */
@objc(StatusBarPlugin)
public class StatusBarPlugin: CAPPlugin {
    private var observer: NSObjectProtocol?

    override public func load() {
        observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name.capacitorStatusBarTapped, object: .none, queue: .none) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.bridge?.triggerJSEvent(eventName: "statusTap", target: "window")
        }
    }

    deinit {
        if let observer = observer {
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }

    @objc func setStyle(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
        let options = call.options!

        if let style = options["style"] as? String {
            if style == "DARK" {
                bridge?.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
            } else if style == "LIGHT" {
                bridge?.statusBarStyle = .darkContent
            } else if style == "DEFAULT" {
                bridge?.statusBarStyle = .default
            }
        }

        call.resolve([:])
    }

    @objc func setBackgroundColor(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
        let options = call.options

        if let color = options?["color"] as? String {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first {
                    let statusBarView = UIView(frame: window.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame ?? CGRect.zero)
                    if let uiColor = UIColor(hexString: color) {
                        statusBarView.backgroundColor = uiColor
                        window.addSubview(statusBarView)
                        if uiColor.isLight {
                            self.bridge?.statusBarStyle = .darkContent
                         } else {
                            self.bridge?.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        call.resolve([:])
    }

    func setAnimation(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
        let animation = call.getString("animation", "FADE")
        if animation == "SLIDE" {
            bridge?.statusBarAnimation = .slide
        } else if animation == "NONE" {
            bridge?.statusBarAnimation = .none
        } else {
            bridge?.statusBarAnimation = .fade
        }
    }

    @objc func hide(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
        setAnimation(call)
        bridge?.statusBarVisible = false
        call.resolve()
    }

    @objc func show(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
        setAnimation(call)
        bridge?.statusBarVisible = true
        call.resolve()
    }

    @objc func getInfo(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            guard let bridge = self?.bridge else {
                return
            }
            let style: String
            switch bridge.statusBarStyle {
            case .default:
                if bridge.userInterfaceStyle == UIUserInterfaceStyle.dark {
                    style = "DARK"
                } else {
                    style = "LIGHT"
                }
            case .lightContent:
                style = "DARK"
            default:
                style = "LIGHT"
            }

            call.resolve([
                "visible": bridge.statusBarVisible,
                "style": style
            ])
        }
    }

    @objc func setOverlaysWebView(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
        call.unimplemented()
    }
}

extension UIColor {
    convenience init?(hexString: String) {
        
        var hexSanitized = hexString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        hexSanitized = hexSanitized.replacingOccurrences(of: "#", with: "")
        print("Failed to scan hex value.",hexSanitized)
        var rgb: UInt64 = 0

        guard Scanner(string: hexSanitized).scanHexInt64(&rgb) else { return nil }

        self.init(red: CGFloat((rgb & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
                  green: CGFloat((rgb & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
                  blue: CGFloat(rgb & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
                  alpha: 1.0)
          }
    var isLight: Bool {
          var white: CGFloat = 0
          getWhite(&white, alpha: nil)
          return white > 0.7
      }
    
}
```

**now you can set the status bar color by using**

```
import { StatusBar } from '@capacitor/status-bar';

StatusBar.setBackgroundColor({ color : '#E31936' });
```

with the above we are now managing both platforms

**PLEASE NOTE  : When you delete platform folder (ios) you may need to override the above file again and again as this is a workaround until @capacitor/status-bar plugin add the support for background color method**